# Cannot setAttribute for dynamically loaded text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to import records from a database and apply a class to those records. The records are imported properly, but I lose the class reference and the css for the imported text. I try to reset the attribute, but it does not take. 
Notice that I've commented out the line that imports the text from the database:

```
document.getElementById("tablesorter-demo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

When I do this, the existing html text works properly. How can I import the text and apply the class (i.e. apply the tablesorter class") and the css to the imported text?

```
getElement.setAttribute("class", "tablesorter");
```

Thanks for your time!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">
 <head>
<title>Tablesorter</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="__jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {      
    $("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter({sortList:[[0,0],[2,1]], widgets: ['zebra']});
    $("#options").tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0]], headers: { 3:{sorter: false}, 4:{sorter: false}}});
}); 

window.onload = function() { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            //console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            //document.getElementById("tablesorter-demo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            var getElement = document.getElementById("tablesorter-demo")
            getElement.setAttribute("class", "tablesorter");
            getElement.setAttribute("border", "1");
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","createTableList.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
   </head>
 <body>
 <div id="main">
 <table id='tablesorter-demo' >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Login ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>120</td>
            <td>Jenny</td>
            <td>Jones</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>121</td>
            <td>Billy</td>
            <td>Bob</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>

 </body>
 class</html>
```

Comment: You're probably not loosing the class, but the jQuery plugin doesn't work with dynamic content unless you set it up to work with dynamic content. Also, why aren't you using jQuery for the ajax request and setting classes and styles, it's what jQuery does best ?

Comment: leverage jQuery to make an ajax call and then call the `tablesorter` method on the required elements on the `success` callback for ajax. More on jQuery.ajax https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Unfortunately there is not enough information for me to understand how to proceed. Let me follow up: What does it mean to use 'jQuery for the ajax request' I am using a php file to send my data-- is there a better way to do this? Likewise, what does it mean to 'leverage jQuery to make an ajax call'? I thought that what I was doing was importing data then applying a method to it. Finally, how do I set up jQuery to work with dynamic data-- is there something special I need to do. I'm an experienced programmer, but js/ jQuery is all new for me, so please be gentle!